# What does a dot after a number mean?

Tags: notation, wolfram-alpha

So I'm making some calculations for numerical analysis and the output I get in Wolfram or Mathematica for input like:

```
-0.666667 (x-1) (x-0.5) (x+0.5)+0.166666 (x-1) (x+1) (x+0.5)+0.499999 (x-1) (x-0.5) (x+1)
```

Is:

```
-2.x10^-6 x^3+0.500001 x^2-0.499998 x-2.5x10^-7
```

So:

$-2.\cdot10^{-6} x^3+0.500001 x^2-0.499998 x-2.5\cdot 10^-7$

My question is, what does this dot in -2.x mean? Does it mean we don't know decimal places or something like that?

Comment: It's a decimal point. Alpha explicitly shows it to designate that it's an inexact number.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is trying to tell you that it is not exactly $2$, but very close to $2$. Try using fractions to gain an exact answer:

```
-2/3 (x-1) (x-1/2) (x+1/2)+ 1/6 (x-1) (x+1) (x+1/2)+ 1/2 (x-1) (x-1/2) (x+1)
```

Which is $\frac{x^2 - x}{2}$.